# Google Sheets formula: networkdays exept holidays (from Google Calendar)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a possibility of using the `NETWORKDAYS` function including weekends and holidays from the Google Calendar?

Google Calendar includes holidays in my country and I want to use it to count working days in every month but I haven't any idea how to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

this is how to use `NETWORKDAYS`:

[image: 0]

column **D** contains predefined holidays